# Trouble reading txt file in Love2D

Tags: file, lua, love2d

I am trying to read from a txt file in Lua, as shown below (main.lua):

```
local function read_file(filename)
    contents = io.open(filename, "r")
    if contents == nil then
        return false
    else
        io.close(contents)
        return true
    end
end

if read_file("myfile.txt") then
    print("Yes")
else
    print("Not found")
end
```

However, it keeps returning "Not found" even though myfile.txt is in the same directory as main.lua. I am currently using Lua with Love2D engine.

Comment: The path in `io.open` is relative to the "current directory", not the directory of the main script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you might be tempted to use Lua's [`io`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.8) in LÖVE I would suggest against it.

LÖVE has it's own [`love.filesystem`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem). Consider:

```lua
if love.filesystem.getInfo("myfile.txt") then
   print("Yes")
   print(love.filesystem.read("myfile.txt"))
else
   print("Not found")
end
```

Behaviour of the `love.filesystem` is consistent between platforms supported by LÖVE and, in short, for selected operations it is:

- **Write**/**append** - path of the file is relative to the *save directory*.
- **Read** - path is first resolved against the *save directory*. If nothing is found then path is resolved against the content of the *love* archive or (if applicable) the source directory.

*Save directory* is a special directory for use of your application. In case of doubts, please refer to [LÖVE's wiki](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem).

As for why the example from the question might not be working - please see Egor's comment.